# Load content created dynamically where scrolling using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

Is that possible to use jQuery plugin like [Infinite Ajax Scroll](http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin) to load content which is dynamically created with JavaScript ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

this is base

```
$(window).scroll(function(){


if($(this).scrollTop()+$(this).height() == $("body").get(0).scrollHeight){  
// call function 
}

})
```

Comment: This is not what I want! 
I want my data load when I scroll part  by part and not all at once, because in my case I am trying to handle hundreds of lines.

Comment: in this case, when you call the function that loads you send a LIMIT and OFFSET to carry the load according to the limit and offset.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question would be "Yes, it is possible".

Please read the guidelines on how to post appropriate question, so you can get the best of the community.

The plugin has extensive documentation, I'd advise you read it first.

https://github.com/webcreate/Infinite-Ajax-Scroll#readme

And demos:

http://www.fieg.nl/ias-demo

View the source code on the demos to get a better explanation how to use it.